# Ruby array to html table with two lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array:

```
[[14, "E"], [19, "E"], [22, "E"], [24, "E"], [25, "E"], [26, "C"], [5, "E"], [8, "C"], [9, "E"], [10, "C"]]
```

I need to have a table like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>22</td>
      ...
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>E</td>
      ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do that with that array ? is it a better option convert to hash and work with keys and values?

Comment: If `arr` is your array perhaps you just want `values, letters = arr.transpose; values #=> [14, 19, 22, 24, 25, 26, 5, 8, 9, 10]; letters #=> ["E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "C", "E", "C", "E", "C"]`.

Comment: `E`, `E`, `E` don't make a good example. Why don't you pick varying values?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
tr_1 = array.map {|i| i[0]}
tr_2 = array.map {|i| i[1]}
```